# Traversing INT array in two ways

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, loops, arduino

Traversing INT array in two ways is a robotic funny code (in C).

I have an array of positions like this: `int pos[] = {0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 135, 90, 45};`
These positions are used to move a servo motor.

```
 45   90   135
   \   |   /
    \  |  /
     \ | /
0 ----------- 180
```

In main `loop()` I check distance from an obstacle, and if it's `< xx Cm` my servo must rotate to next step (next array position) until it finds a free way ( `> xx Cm` ).

My main is easy:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) { for (;;) find(); }
```

and my core function (find) is this:

```
void find() {
    for ( i=0; i<sizeof(pos); i++ ) // Traversing position array
    {
        distance = rand() % 7; // Simulate obstacle distance

        move( pos[i] );  // Simulate movements

        if (i==sizeof(pos)) { i=1; } // Try to reset the "i" counter. PROBLEM!
        if ( distance<=5 ) continue; // Is there an obstacle?

        sleep(2); // Debug sleep
        find(); // Similar recursion
    }
}
```

I don't know what is wrong in this code, but I need to move servo until is there not an obstacle.

---

**Example**:
At position `90` I find an obstacle. I want to loop array from left to right and viceversa controlling distance every step.  If I don't find a freeway, `print("ko")` else `print("ok")`.

How do I fix this code to work correctly?

Comment: There are several problems with your code, that might add up to your indexing problems. Your `find` doesn't have a prototype, very bad. You are giving us no declaration of `i`. A global variable? Of what type? All of `i`, `distance`, `pos` should be either local variables or parameters to your function.

Comment: @Jens, it's a **simulation, not real code**. It's obvious that are missing `double distance` and prototype for `find`, but it's not important to solve the problem! I write manually this snippet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the servo to make a sweeping movement from left to right and then back from right to left. Measuring the distance to an object that can be in front of the robot at each angle. If there is a free way ahead of the robot, the find method returns.

```
int pos[] = {0, 45, 90, 135, 180, -1};

void find()
{
    int i = 0;
    int direction = 1;

    do {
        move(pos[i]);
        i += direction;
        if (pos[i+direction] == -1) direction = -1; 
        if (i==0) direction = 1;
    } while(measure_distance() <= 5); 
}
```

Instead of recursion, there is a while loop that only exits when there is a distance greater then 5.

The 'pos' array has a sentinel at the end (-1). This is an invalid angle and can be used to find the end of the array. There is no need to calculate the number of elements.

The left-right, right-left movement comes from using the 'direction' variable. It is rather easy to detect either the beginning (i==0) or the end of the 'pos' array (pos[i+1] == -1), at which point we reverse the direction.

There is also no need to repeat the angles after 180 degrees. The sequence we get is:

> 0 45 90 135 180 135 90 45 0 45 90 ...

We can even reduce the code with one line...

```
...
if (pos[i+direction] == -1 || i == 0) direction *= -1; 
...
```

Cheers,
Johan

Answer (score 3):

You really want `i < sizeof(pos) / sizeof(*pos)` rather than `i < sizeof(pos)`. The size of an array is not the number of its elements but rather the total byte count it occupies in memory.

`sizeof(pos)` yields `8 * sizeof(int)`. If an `int` is 4 bytes, you are looping 32 times instead of 8.

Also, `i == sizeof(pos)` will never be true in the body of the loop because the condition of the `for` statement limits `i` to `sizeof(pos) - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to initialize your rand function using

```
/* initialize random seed: */
srand ( time(NULL) );

distance = rand() % 7;
```

Comment: thanks, but rand() is not used in real proj. It's a simulation

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop. Increment the value when there is no obstacle and break when you find an obstruction:

```
{
    ......
    ......
    i = rand()%7;
    move( pos[i]);

    if (i<5)
        break;
    else
        continue;
    .......
    .......
}
```

This will randomly choose the position until you get an obstacle and also there will be no need to reset it as the loop will automatically break on encountering an obstacle.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably good practise to say:
`#define POSLENGTH 8`
 and then iterate using `i<POSLENGTH`: as others have pointed out using `sizeof(pos)` is probably not going to work.

Also, arrays in C are 0 based: elements go 0,1,2,3,...n-1.
So, you need to say:

`if (i==POSLENGTH-1) i=0;`